# Is there a mathematical name for a "pillow" shape?

Tags: geometry, terminology

Is there a mathematical name for the shape you get when stitching two squares or rectangles together along all four edges, and then "inflating" it?

I've been calling this a "pillow" shape, but I'm sure it must have a real name.

There's a similar-ish problem called a "Mylar Balloon", but involves two circles stitched together instead of squares or rectangles: [Mylar Balloon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mylar_balloon_(geometry))

My friend also stumbled on the term "squinch vault" that looks about right:

[image: squinch vault]

However, this seems to be an architectural term and not a mathematical one.

Comment: Related (duplicate?): ["What's the correct name for a geometric solid that's a beanbag?"](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/98049/409). [An answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/98393/409) cites the note ["Profiles of Inflated Surfaces" (PDF link via ucla.edu)](https://www.math.ucla.edu/~pak/papers/Schlenker7.pdf) that simply uses the term "[square or rectangular] pillow".

Comment: The figure is topologically a cone over the rectangle where top and bottom are seamed.  It would go be helpful to sketch your intended use for terminology, as the word *pillow* suggests lack of rigidity.